# Batch CMD - Extract text upto last special character

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I am trying to extract a path location without the file name. For example the log file generated by a program will have a string similar to the below:

```
2021-03-24T13:34:15 - Processing: C:\Source\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\File1-???????????.txt
```

What I would need to extract from the log file is the below:

> C:\Source\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3

So far I am able to get:

> C:\Source\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\File1-???????????????????????.txt"

using the following code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^<"C:\Source0\sample.txt" find "Processing:"') do set _path="%%a"

set _path_=%_path:~35%

echo %_path_%
```

Please assist me in showing how to omit the File1*-????? part of the string

EDIT: The file1-????? part is not fixed in character length and neither are the subdirectors which can go further down in level. The only part that is fixed are the first 35 characters of the string which I omit using %_path:~35%.

Comment: BTW, I counted only 34 characters, to omit from the beginning of the string, although my answer below doesn't do any counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work for you:

In [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) as a [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line):

```sh
For /F "Tokens=3,*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Processing:" 0^<"C:\Source0\sample.txt"') Do @For %I In ("%~dpH.") Do @Echo %~dpnxI
```

Or as a [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=3,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Processing:" 0^<"C:\Source0\sample.txt"') Do @For %%I In ("%%~dpH.") Do @Echo %%~dpnxI
```

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you have something that works. Another way to do it would be with PowerShell that is already on your supported Windows system. This looks long, but it could be reduced by not checking so closely for the date and time.

```
SET "THESTRING=2021-03-24T13:34:15 - Processing: C:\Source\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\File1-???????????.txt"

REM === Find the full file name
SET "PART=no match"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "if ('%THESTRING%' -match '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} - Processing: .*\\(.*)\.txt.*') {" ^
    "$Matches[1]"}') DO (SET "PART=%%~A")
ECHO PART IS ===%PART%===

REM === Find the part of the name after the HYPHEN character
SET "PART=no match"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "if ('%THESTRING%' -match '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} - Processing: .*\\.*-(.*)\.txt.*') {" ^
    "$Matches[1]"}') DO (SET "PART=%%~A")
ECHO PART IS ===%PART%===
```

It would be easier if it was not run in CMD.EXE.

```
$TheSting=2021-03-24T13:34:15 - Processing: C:\Source\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\File1-???????????.txt"
$Part = if ('%TheString%' -match '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} - Processing: .*\\(.*)\.txt.*') { "$Matches[1]" }
```